# JMSSecurityExtraBundle nested AND/OR expressions

Tags: symfony, annotations

I have this @PreAuthorize annotation:

```
@PreAuthorize("(hasRole('PERM_EDIT_ALL_CAMPAIGNS') or (has_role('PERM_EDIT_OWN_CAMPAIGNS') and isCampaignAccountManager(#id))) and (hasRole('PERM_EDIT_ALL_PUBLISHERS') or (has_role('PERM_EDIT_OWN_PUBLISHERS') and isAffiliateAccountManager(#paramFetcher.get('affiliate_id'))))")
```

I get the following error:

> Expected primary expression, but got \u0022has_role\u0022 of type T_NONE at position
>    40 (0-based)

So the error looks like to appear after the bracket beginning here:

> (has_role('PERM_EDIT_OWN_CAMPAIGNS') and isCampaignAccountManager(#id)))

Is there any way to add brackets in and/or expressions?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OMG!! sorry, I just realized after I wrote the question. I was using 'has_role' instead 'hasRole' :(